# Would this wiring question be appropriate on DIY.SE?

Tags: discussion, questions

We have a [question on physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12166/electric-wires) about electrical wiring, which is off topic there. It didn't jump out at me as home improvement at first, but the people on the EE site suggested it might fit here... is that the case? If the question would be appropriate here I'd like to migrate it.

Comment: Looks good to me, though appliance repair is borderline so it might get closed.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking. But since it seems like the question at least might be okay, I'll migrate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like it might be OK (at first glance).

It needs some editing to bring in the images, or at least make them all links though.